# Emacs: How to associate different initialization configurations with different file formats?

Tags: emacs

What's the best way to associate file extensions with my own customizations? For example, when I open a .py file the frame would be bigger and split into 2 windows, but when a .tex file is opened the frame would be smaller with just one window. Should I split my .emacs and write all configurations associated with python in a .el file (key bindings, python shell = ipython, etc ...) and for latex in another .el file (load auctex, pdf mode = default, etc ...)? How would I "call" the files and make them work appropriately (if that'a possible and good solution)?

Comment: Are you talking about initialisation as in starting Emacs with `emacs foo.py` vs `emacs foo.tex` (with subsequent actions, such as `C-x C-f bar.py`, being unaffected)? Or do you want special things to (potentially) happen *every time* you visit a .py file or a .tex file in any way? If it's the latter, I think you need to consider your requirements in more detail (but most generally you would use major mode hooks to evaluate code specific to each major mode, when that mode is called in any buffer; or perhaps `find-file-hook` to act on visited files regardless of mode).

Comment: Most of the tasks I want emacs to perform (related to my question) are the second kind you described, so major mode hooks would be the solution. However there are some of the first kind, for example the windows configuration. I wouldn't want the window size and position to change every time I change major mode, it would be just when starting emacs with emacs file.py

Answer (score 1):

(First, +1 to @phils's comment.  You will get better help if you are more specific about what you need/want.)

Depending on just what you need/want, see also variable (not option) `file-name-handler-alist`.  You might not need it, but you might.

You can make use of it if you intend all or particular operations on the files to involve additional actions (such as those you describe).  For any operations where you do not need special treatment, just provide the default behavior.  For the others, provide the default behavior plus the extra behavior (in whichever order is appropriate).

See (elisp) [`Magic File Names`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Magic-File-Names.html) for more information.